# Horizontal linearLayout's children out of screen

Tags: android

I have a horizontal `linearLayout` in a `frameLayout`. many `textViews` will add to `linearLayout` dynamically. below is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/an_item_tags_lay"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </LinearLayout>
```

and the function that add `textViews` is:

```
private void createTags(){

ArrayList<String> arr_tags  = new ArrayList<>();
arr_tags.add("#flower");
arr_tags.add("#red");
arr_tags.add("#flower");
arr_tags.add("#red");
arr_tags.add("#flower");
arr_tags.add("#red");
arr_tags.add("#flower");
arr_tags.add("#red");
arr_tags.add("#flower");
arr_tags.add("#red");
arr_tags.add("#flower");
arr_tags.add("#red");

for(int i = 0; i < arr_tags.size(); i++){

    TextView tag = new TextView(getActivity());
    tag.setId(i);
    tag.setText(arr_tags.get(i));
    tag.setTextColor(r.getColor(R.color.color_an_item_btn_tag_darker_color));
    tag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_tag_select);
    tag.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(4, 10, 4, 4);
    tag.setLayoutParams(params);

    an_item_tags_lay.addView(tag);

}

}
```

the result is as following image: 
[image]

as you can see in the image, `textViews` will go out of screen. I would like when the screen is full, other views come to the next line. what property should I add to `linearLayout`? is there any `view` for this behavior?

Comment: Why don't you have a fixed number of textViews in a row? say 5 per row and you need to have 1 vertical and as many horizontal linear view as you want to accommodate textViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply use [flow layout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need a add it programatically something like this:

```
tagViews.removeAllViews();
                            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            LinearLayout childView;
                            int remainingWidth, count = tagViews.getChildCount();
                            if (count <= 0)
                                tagViews.addView(ll);
                            TextView tagText;

                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

                            int width = 0;
                            WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
                            Point size = new Point();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                                w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
                                width = size.x;
                            } else {
//            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
//            width = d.getWidth();
                                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                                width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                                //int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                            }
                            try {
                                for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(k);
                                    MyProductsCatTagHandler model = new MyProductsCatTagHandler();
                                    model.setName(obj.getString("category_name"));
                                    model.setId(obj.getString("cat_id"));
                                    tagModels.add(model);
                                    final String cat_name = obj.getString("category_name");
                                    final String cat_id = obj.getString("cat_id");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < tagViews.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        childView = (LinearLayout) tagViews.getChildAt(i);
                                        tagText = new TextView(this);
                                        CommonUtilities.setTypeface(this, tagText, CommonUtilities.VIEW_TYPE.TEXTVIEW, CommonUtilities.TYPE_FACE.CALLIBRI, 0);
                                        tagText.setText(cat_name);
                                        tagText.setLayoutParams(params);
                                        tagText.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
                                        //tagText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xee, 0xee, 0xee));
                                        tagText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tags_bg);
                                        // count = holder.tagViews.getChildCount();
                                        childView.measure(0, 0);
                                        remainingWidth = width - childView.getMeasuredWidth();
                                        //// Log.v("subcriptionAdapter", "remaining width=" + remainingWidth + " childview width= " + childView.getMeasuredWidth());
                                        try {
                                            if (remainingWidth > childView.getMeasuredWidth()) {
                                                childView.addView(tagText);
                                                childView.invalidate();
                                                break;
                                            } else if ((i == tagViews.getChildCount() - 1) && (remainingWidth < childView.getMeasuredWidth())) {
                                                childView = new LinearLayout(this);
                                                childView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                                                childView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                                childView.addView(tagText);
                                                tagViews.addView(childView);
                                                childView.invalidate();
                                                break;
                                            } else {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            tagViews.invalidate();
                        }
```

Comment: This wouldn't bring the textviews to nextline as Shima Erfan wants

Answer (score 0):

Do you want only one element to be displayed in a row or multiple elements?

If only one element, then you can use [Listview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). Else you can use [Table layout][2] or [Grid View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) according to your need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want multiple elements, as much as the screen can display.

Comment: @ShimaErfan google for `android flow layout`, there are lots of them

Comment: @pskink has suggested a very nice solution. Thanks.